# Save image on server from signed applet

Tags: java, image, applet

In my signed applet I have an `Image` object, Now I want to save this `Image` at `getCodebase()` by creating a new file. I use:

```
File file2=new File(getCodeBase()+"newFile.gif");
file2.createNewFile();
ImageIO.write(myImage, "png", file2);
```

To create new file then `ImageIO` to write file at this destination but it gives the following error.

```
http://192.168.1.119:96/res/applet/newFile.gif
pgraph.sendImageToServer... exceptionThe filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
```

How to save image on the server from a signed applet?

Comment: `new File(getCodeBase()+"newFile.gif");`  BTW - an `URL` + a `String` does not add up to a valid `File` path.  It would be wise to inspect the values with a debugger, or at least print them to the console.  Programming languages work on logic, not magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If an applet establishes a `File` object, that `File` will point to somewhere on the file-system of the end user's PC.  It can *never* point back to the server.
2. For an applet to save anything on a server, it needs to return the bytes of the resource to a script on the server that does the part of saving the image.
3. If an applet is 'phoning home' to its own server to save an image, it does not need to be digitally signed.